# android phone or small device with qwerty physical keyboard with Ctrl and Alt keys?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any Android phone or similarly-sized device with qwerty physical keyboard including Ctrl and Alt keys? What do sysadmins use for typing on Android devices?

Comment: This looks like a shopping recommendation (off-topic).  That said, why would you administer a system from a phone instead of a computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Android doesn't really have Control or Alt, you might be able to get a virtual keyboard with them but I very much doubt there's a device with them on a physical keyboard.

Your best bet is a shell with support for these keys. [Terminal Emulator](https://market.android.com/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) does Ctrl+key by holding Volume Down and pressing the key, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Not a physical keyboard, but the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) soft keyboard has Control and Alt keys on the keyboard.